# Android WebView HTML 5 performance

Tags: android, html, performance, webview

In my app, I want to include a webview containing for example a simple HTML 5 game. On a new phone with Android 5.0, this works great, but on an older phone, running Android 4.4.2, the performance is terrible. In the chrome browser, the game is performing perfectly, but in the webview of my app, it is very slow and laggy.

I have tried some performance optimizations like enabling hardware acceleration, but nothing resulted in a better performance. Therefore, I looked for alternatives to the webview, and using [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) resulted in a very good performance. But now, the problem is that Crosswalk adds 18MB to the apk size and 45MB to the phone memory usage. As that is simply too much for just a simple app like mine, Crosswalk unfortunately turned out to be no option.

Is there a way that improves webview performance, but does not increase the memory usage as drastically as Crosswalk does?

Answer (score 0):

The core problem that you will face with using the stock WebView built into Android is that it is terribly inconsistent in terms of performance and what it supports regarding HTML5/CSS. While CrossWalk may add 18MB to the size of your app, it is worth it if your concern is performance and compatibility across devices and Android variants.

Your other alternative is CocoonJS, however without knowing more about your app, it's hard to say if this will benefit you or not.

https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/